# git - rewrite new changes by old one

Tags: git

We use git with "Merge request/approve" policy.
We have main branch "dev" as master, with follow commits:

```
C1 -> C2 -> C3 -> C4 -> MERGE_A3_TO_C
```

We have files changed in C2:

- file1.cpp (v1)
- file2.cpp (v1)

We have files changed in C4:

- file1.cpp (v2)
- file2.cpp (v2)

We had some branch A, branched from C1, with commits:

```
A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> MERGE_C2_TO_A
```

We have file changed in branch A, commit A3:

- file2.cpp (v3)

The illustration:

[image: git flow]

Further:

1. dev merged into C, but dev's HEAD was C2.
2. A with HEAD A3 merged into dev with HEAD C4
3. file2.cpp got conflicted state.
4. We resolve the conflict.

As result we had:

- file1.cpp (v1)
- file2.cpp (v1 + v3)

**Version 2 of files just disapeared.**

We tried to make:

*-m 1 - good state of branch*

```
git checkout dev 
git revert MERGE_A3_TO_C -m 1   
git checkout A
git revert MERGE_C2_TO_A  -m 1
git merge dev
git checkout dev
git merge A
```

Which is:

1. Revert of MERGE_A3_TO_C and MERGE_C2_TO_A
2. Merge C4 into A3 -> MERGE_C4_TO_A
3. Merge MERGE_C4_TO_A into C4
4. Resolve conflict

Still same problem.

*The problem isn't conflict of course, the problem is vanishing of v2 of the files*

Further we used:

```
git checkout A
git reset --hard A3
git checkout dev
git reset --hard C4
git merge A
git push --force origin dev
```

The questions:

1. Why v2 disapeared?
2. Is it possible to solve it with git revert, neither with git reset?